# Typescript error: Property '_myApiUrl' does not exist on type 'Window'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript and I run into a problem. I had this method in a Typescript (.ts) file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [Service1, Service2]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
// more code here
    myMethod() {
       this.isLoading = true;
       const serverPath = 'http://myApiUrl';
       // more code here
    }
// more code here
}
```

I have replaced `http://myApiUrl`with a variable `window._myApiUrl` and I get the error:

```
Property '_myApiUrl' does not exist on type 'Window' 

myMethod() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    const serverPath = window._myApiUrl;
    // more code here
}
```

Why does this happen? How can I fix the issue?

Comment: where and when do you add _myApiUrl to the window object? Most probably you are using its value before it is initialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript doesn't know that variable exists. You can declare it:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        _myApiUrl: string;
    }
}

export class...
```

Comment: Where should  this piece of code be inserted? I inserted it after `export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {` and it throws an error. As I mentioned, I am new to this.

Comment: Insert it before `export class`. Or user declaration files: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

Comment: I would recommend creating a config file to keep all urls and acccess them from there instead of using the window object.

Comment: I added `declare global {
    interface Window {
        _myApiUrl: string;
    }
}` between the component declaration and `export class` and I get a `Decorators are not valid here.`

Comment: Above the decorator too.